# Overriding a block in CE 1.7

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, blocks

I'm trying to override a method within **Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Autocomplete.php** (to display a maximum of 5 results for the search autocomplete)

Now I just want to make sure I'm doing this correctly. I have defined my class in this block's **config.xml**:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <tag>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Test_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </tag>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

My question about this part is:

Do I specify everything within the `<blocks>` node within the config file's `<blocks>` node? or do I use the above structure separately? I assume the former but want to make sure.

Once I complete the above, I assume I just need to create the class (within the local codepool), extend it and then override the method I have in mind? Something like this:

```
class Test_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete {

    public function getSuggestData() {
    if (!$this->_suggestData) {
        # The line I'm overriding ..
        $collection = $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getSuggestCollection()->setPageSize(5);;
        $query = $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();
        $counter = 0;
        $data = array();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $_data = array(
                'title' => $item->getQueryText(),
                'row_class' => (++$counter)%2?'odd':'even',
                'num_of_results' => $item->getNumResults()
            );

            if ($item->getQueryText() == $query) {
                array_unshift($data, $_data);
            }
            else {
                $data[] = $_data;
            }
        }
        $this->_suggestData = $data;
        }
    return $this->_suggestData;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Magento and just want to make sure I'm on the right tracks. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<config>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <!-- register your block -->
        <mymodule>
            <class>MyPackage_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mymodule>
        <!-- Which block you overwrite -->
        <catalogsearch>
            <rewrite>
                <autocomplete>MyPackage_Mymodule_Block_Autocomplete</autocomplete>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Configuration done. If you need another block overwrite, only add after `</catalogsearch>`.
Now you need to extend main block class. like

```
class MyPackage_Mymodule_Block_Autocomplete extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Autocomplete {
}
```

Comment: The first snipped goes into the Module's **config.xml** right? Or does it have to be in it's own **config.xml**? And for the class, I would use the same folder structure that the module does right? (except within the local codepool).

Comment: The first snipped goes into the Module's config.xml right? - it's custom module config.xml(app/code/local/MyPackage/Mymodule/etc/config.xml). CodePool depend on your module configuration, like MyPackage_Mymodule.xml inside "app/etc/modules".